# How can I get or extract only ID string part from embedded google map html code?

Tags: php, html, google-maps

I'm working on travelling website's CMS and I need to show embedded route map on website. I'm unable to figure out how do I extract some part of text/ID from whole embedded code? **Is it possible to do in PHP?**

Following is the embedded code:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=12ECwgUiQPMTqebkaNo-0KLbDwPMeUskHUxmR" width="100%" height="400" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

I only want the `mid` part from the above code, Following is the output that I need:

```
12ECwgUiQPMTqebkaNo-0KLbDwPMeUskHUxmR
```

Please help me to solve this nightmare.....

Comment: Hi Pawan, just as a friendly comment: Stack Overflow users really love to help (if they are able to, on PHP I have to pass - though I'd guess that regular expression is generally a good answer to your problem...). Anyhow: You are expected to show at least a bit what you already tried. Please update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `preg_match` to hunt for the `mid=...` part of the string and extract that:

```
$html = '<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=12ECwgUiQPMTqebkaNo-0KLbDwPMeUskHUxmR" width="100%" height="400" frameborder="0"></iframe>';
preg_match('/mid=([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/', $html, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

Output:

```
12ECwgUiQPMTqebkaNo-0KLbDwPMeUskHUxmR
```

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help.

Comment: Is it possible in jQuery?

Comment: @PawanMall yes, but that's completely different from the PHP solution so worth asking another question...